# Isabelle/HOL error Type unification failed: Clash of types "nat" and "_ set" Type error in application: incompatible operand type

Tags: isabelle

Im really new to isabelle, this is my problem

```
theory MyTheory3
  imports Main
begin
(* 3.1) a) define a type natpair, whose elements are pairs of natural numbers.*)
datatype natpair = Natpair "nat × nat"

(*3.1 b)define a function of type natpair ⇒ nat that returns the sum of the elements of a pair of natural
numbers.*)
definition natpair_sum :: "natpair ⇒ nat" where
  "Natpair((a::nat) × (b::nat)) = a + b"
end
```

i get the error

> Type unification failed: Clash of types "nat" and "_ set"
>
> Type error in application: incompatible operand type
>
> Operator:  (×) :: ??'a set ⇒ ??'b set ⇒ (??'a × ??'b) set Operand:   a
> :: nat

in addition, can someone show me an example of natpair with a parameterized
constructor

Thanks in advance
youre nuric

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues:

1. Operator `(×)` is not a constructor for pairs but the Cartesian product of sets; pairs are constructed using the syntax `(a, b)` or `Pair a b`.
2. The definition `natpair_sum` does not use its name in the equation, that is, the correct syntax is `definition natpair_sum :: "natpair ⇒ nat" where "natpair_sum ... = ..."`.
3. Pattern matching is not allowed in the left-hand side of a `definition`; you can use the `case` construct in the right-hand side of the `definition` or you can use functions instead.
4. There is no need to add type annotations for the components of the pair.

As examples, here are two possible definitions for `natpair_sum`:

```
  definition natpair_sum :: "natpair ⇒ nat" where
    "natpair_sum np = (case np of Natpair (a, b) ⇒ a + b)"

  fun natpair_sum :: "natpair ⇒ nat" where
    "natpair_sum (Natpair (a, b)) = a + b"
```

As for your last question, I'm not quite sure what you mean by "an example of natpair with a parameterized constructor". `Natpair` is already a data constructor which takes a pair of `nat`'s as the only parameter.